# What's the measure of the segment $LR$ in the figure below?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference:In the picture shown we have an isosceles trapezoide,
The $QR$ side measures $b$ and the $PQ$ side measures $a$. find $LR$
(answer:$\frac{b(a+b)}{a-b}$ )
[image]
My progress:

I didn't get much on this question... a colleague indicated if PQRL form a harmonic range. we would have a quick solution. But it would be necessary to demonstrate that these points form a harmonic range ou or if someone sees another solution...

$LR = x\\
\frac{a+b+x}{x}=\frac{a}{b}\\
ax=ba+b.b+bx\\
ax - bx=b(a+b) \\
x(a-b) = b(a+b)\\ \therefore x = \frac{b(a+b)}{(a-b)}$

**Edit**: I found a way to demonstrate that points L, R, Q and P form a harmonic range:

$\angle DCP = 2\theta\\\angle DCB = 2\alpha\\\therefore \boxed{\alpha + \theta = 90^o}\\O ~is~ excenter~ \triangle ARL\\\angle LOR = \alpha\\O ~is~ excenter~ \triangle QCP\\\angle QOP = \theta\\\\ \angle ROQ = 90^o-\theta = \alpha \\
\triangle LOQ:\\
 OR \text{ is angle bissector internal}\\
 \text{OP is angle bissector external} $

[image]

[image]

Comment: @ACB  There was an error in the position of the Q point..I corrected it but I don't know if it will be useful

Comment: @ACB  I posted the demonstration that the points L, R, Q and P form a harmonic range...so the problem is solved

Comment: @ACB $\angle LAR = 2\alpha$ therefore $\angle LOR = \frac{2\alpha}{2} = \alpha$      post to image of property of the property of the angle formed by the angle bissector internal and angle bissector external

Comment: that is good work but you should state that those angles mean that the pencil $ O (LQ; RP)$ is harmonic. See Theorem $4$ for more details. https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c1642h1016535_harmonic_divisions__a_powerful_amp_rarely_used_tool

Comment: There is also algebraic solution. $LR=x$, $AR=y$, $RD=z$, then express all intervals length in terms of $a,b,x,y,z$, using similarity and the fact that AB+CD=AD+BC. Equation AR+BP=AB+PR then can be solved for $y$. Then expression in left-hand side of LQ+BC-CQ-BL =0 can be factored and one of the factors is $bx-ax+b^2+ab$. Other factor is zero when AD=BC which is impossible by condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Showing the pencil $O (LQ; RP)$ is harmonic definitely makes the work easier. Here is an alternate approach that requires solving a quadratic equation in the end.

[image]

$EF$ is perpendicular bisector of $AD$ and $BC$. In $EFRP$, $\angle FRP = 180^\circ - \angle EPR = 180^\circ - 2\theta$

As $F$ and $T$ are points of tangency on the circle from external point $R$, $OR$ bisects $\angle FRT$ and $\angle ORT = 90^\circ - \theta$

So, $\triangle OTR \sim \triangle PTO$. If $RT = c$ and $r$ is the radius of the circle, we have

$ \displaystyle \frac{c}{r} = \frac{r}{a+b-c} \implies r^2 = c (a+b-c) \tag1$

$\angle CQR = \angle PCQ + \angle CPQ = 180^\circ - 2 \alpha + 2\theta$

As $OQ$ bisects $\angle CQR$, $\angle OQT = 90^\circ + \theta - \alpha$ and it follows that $\angle ROQ = \alpha$

Using your work, $\angle LOR = \alpha$ or alternatively, $\angle OLT = \frac{180^\circ - (2 \alpha + 2\theta)}{2} = 90^\circ - (\alpha + \theta)$

SO, $\angle LOT = \alpha + \theta \implies \angle LOR = \alpha$. So $OR$ is bisector of $\angle LOQ$.

Therefore, $ \displaystyle \frac{OL^2}{OQ^2} = \frac{LR^2}{RQ^2}$

If $LR = x,  ~ \displaystyle \frac{(x+c)^2 + r^2}{r^2 + (b-c)^2} = \frac{x^2}{b^2}$

Or, $b^2 c^2 + 2b^2cx + b^2 r^2 = x^2 ( r^2 + c^2 - 2 bc)$

Plugging in value of $r^2$ from $(1)$ and dividing both sides by $c$,

$b^2 (a+b) + 2b^2 x = (a-b) x^2$

$\implies (a-b) x^2 -   2b^2 x - b^2 (a+b) = 0$

$ ((a-b)x - b(a+b)) (x + b) = 0$

That leads to, $ \displaystyle x = \frac{b (a + b)}{a-b}$